# How to restart a dicord bot after client.close(). Discord.py

Tags: python, flask, discord.py

I've made discord bot using the api in flask. Now it just needs to send messages to a channel. But if I start the bot with flask all the flask code stops. I tried to use client.close and I've got an exception: `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. I've tried to use client.clean in different places, but I am still getting this exception.

Now my code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import discord

global data

app = Flask(__name__)
client = discord.Client()

CHANNEL = <id>

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global data

    channel = client.get_channel(id=CHANNEL)

    await channel.send(f"{data['products'][0]['custom_fields'][0]['discord']}\nТовар : {data['products'][0]['name']}")

    await client.close()
    client.clear()

@app.route('/purchase', methods=['POST'])
def purchase():
    global data
    data = json.loads(request.data)

    client.run('token')

    return data['products'][0]['custom_fields'][0]['discord']
```

Comment: Put the flask part in a different file and use threading to run both files at the same time.

Comment: @FusionSid But how to give data from request to bot?(I am pretty bad in threading)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend to run it in the thread. I had the same issue when I had not to block the main thread of the game-client (I believe this should work with Flask too). Example can be found [here](https://github.com/Igor-ua/python-shared/blob/master/sv_discord/sv_discord.py):

```
import discord
import asyncio

discord_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
client = discord.Client(loop=discord_loop, heartbeat_timeout=20, intents=discord.Intents.all())

def init():
    try:
        asyncio.get_child_watcher()

        global discord_loop
        discord_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        thread = threading.Thread(target=discord_loop.run_forever)
        thread.start()

        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client.connect(reconnect=True), discord_loop)
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client.login(token=DiscordSettings.TOKEN, bot=True), discord_loop)
    except:
        utils.get_and_log_exception_info()


def stop():
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client.logout(), discord_loop)
    discord_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(discord_loop.stop)


def reconnect():
    client.clear()
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client.connect(reconnect=True), discord_loop)
```